# A list of Web Safe Fonts and importing fonts?

Tags: css, webfonts, font-family

I am working on making my own text editor for my website. This text editor is based upon Microsoft Word 2010 with a similar layout and features. I am currently working on the drop down list for the types of font which you can choose and I would like to know if there is a anywhere on the web safe fonts of which you can use.

---

[image]

## Serif Fonts

- Georgia, serif
- "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif
- "Times New Roman", Times, serif

## Sans-Serif Fonts

- Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
- "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif
- "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif
- Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif
- "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif
- Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif
- "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif
- Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif

---

[View this page by clicking here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp)

---

The above content is a preview of some fonts of which you can use, listed on w3schools.com. It lists fonts such as "Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif", of which I do not know what part of this, is the actual font name. On my editor, I would simply like to display a list of most used fonts in a list "Arial, Arial Black, Arial Narrow" and so on. Some of these fonts will not be on safe web fonts and therefore I will have to import the font.

I would like to not only know if there is a better list of web-safe font types your able to have including their simplified name and how to import fonts. Also, regarding importing fonts, once I import them, will they show correctly on all applications/devices?

Comment: This a non-constructive question, based on false premises (there are no web-safe fonts) and w3schools disinformation, and not making clear whether this is about “normal” fonts or downloadable fonts. Regarding the latter, there are many existing questions.

Comment: its not 'non-constructive' at all. even if there are no ABSOLUTE web safe fonts, all the fonts available today get ordered according to their availability across platforms. so there IS a list of "top 10 safest fonts".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at Google Web Fonts for something like this:

[Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/)

Hope this helps

Comment: This, from a glimpse seems brilliant. I am going to go through Google Fonts and see how I can use them and whatnot, and then come back and eithe rleave feedback to +1 and award this as the answer. Thank you and best regards.

Comment: I've been using it all the time since I first found out about it. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can check which fonts work with which OS [here](http://cssfontstack.com/) and [here](http://www.awayback.com/revised-font-stack/).

These websites have the list of web safe fonts along with which OS it can be used with. It is always best and safe to choose fonts that can work on all types of OS.

As mentioned by @Stefen V., [Google fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/) are awesome. However, it has a drawback that it may effect the page load time (makes the page load slower than using web safe fonts).

Answer (score 0):

The examples above which you have given are examples of font trees.

So "Georgia, serif" means use georgia if it's available and if it's not then use any 'serif' font that is available.

And "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" means use Arial if it's available, if it's not available use Helvetica and lastly if that's not available use ans sans-serif font that is available.

Google fonts as mentioned by Stefan V. is a good option although I'm not 100% sure you'll be able to integrate them with your editor. Anything is possible though so you may be able to.

You can either download the indivudual Google fonts to use on your website or just link to them hosted on Google's web servers.